# Should we have translation golf in Portuguese SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I noticed in Spanish SE, there’s a challenge called [Translation Golf](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591), which aims to engage SE users to actively contribute Spanish translations of a given English text. I thought it would be a good method to stimulate greater interaction and discussion, given the current level of activity in Portuguese SE right now. It should be easily implemented, since Portuguese is also a Romance language, so similar rules do apply.

What do you think? Should we introduce regular challenges like this?

P.S.: The rules of the Spanish Translation Golf can be found in the embedded link

Comment: I think it can be a good idea to increase PL activity.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't find much interest in it. I spend my day translating English. What makes Portuguese SE special is the ambience of the community. A place of meeting based on our shared language and for occasional exchange. The content here does come with a considerable degree of quality, but also allowing for casual Q&A.

Comment: The problem with the game is that it denies or removes the genius of the language (whether Spanish or Portuguese). There are tons of examples where you simply cannot have shorter text. One easy example: o portão do jardim= the garden gate.  The beauty of translation is to convey equivalent meaning, not to "castrate it".

Comment: There are also mistakes. One example: Soy feliz por nuestra reunión hoy, **is not** "I am happy to join with you today" (Martin Luther King).